# In Ubuntu 17.10 'plymouth show-splash' does nothing, why?

Tags: boot, themes, plymouth

I've developed a Plymouth Theme and realized I could probably test without rebooting the computer every time.

I discovered '[plymouth show-splash](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Plymouth/Theme_creation)' is suppose to achieve this, but executing that command results in nothing. No error. No success message. No splash screen.

I expected that when I executed this command the Plymouth Theme would take over my screen and appear for X seconds and then disappear.

I'm unable to locate any articles on this topic anywhere. Can someone shed light? Explain why this is happening? Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but if you didn't start the server first `plymouthd --no-daemon --debug` (in another terminal and keep it running) then it explains why the client (`plymouth`) doesn't display your theme

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://antumdeluge.wordpress.com/2016/04/06/plymouth-bootsplash/) post. Here is the summary:

- Paste this code into a file, for example, `plymouth-preview`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

chk_root () {
  if [ ! $( id -u ) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo Must be run as root
    exit
  fi
}

chk_root

DURATION=$1
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  DURATION=5
fi

plymouthd
plymouth --show-splash
for ((I=0; I<$DURATION; I++)); do
  plymouth --update=test$I;
  sleep 1;
  done;
plymouth quit
```

- Open a terminal and make the script executable with the command `chmod +x ./preview-plymouth`.
- Run the script with `./preview-plymouth`. By default, it will show the animation for 5 seconds. If you want to change the duration, type it along with the command. eg. `./preview-plymouth 10` for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This must be executed as root with `sudo plymouth show-splash`

Comment: not working for me